# Unable to install R package paRdot from Github

Tags: r, curl, install.packages, pardot

Trying to install paRdot package in R version 3.5.0 . I have tried creating a new library as well.I get the error as below

> devtools::install_github("demgenman/paRdot")

Downloading GitHub repo demgenman/paRdot@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/demgenman/paRdot/zipball/master
Installing paRdot
"C:/PROGRA1/R/R-351.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ 
--no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL 
"C:/Users/karan/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpA7eMiW/devtools1e8419e4f9f/demgenman-paRdot-db77cca" 
--library="C:/Users/karan/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" 
--install-tests

installing source package 'paRdot' ...
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
converting help for package 'paRdot'
finding HTML links ... done
pardot_account html
pardot_campaigns html
pardot_client html
pardot_email html
pardot_email_clicks html
pardot_email_stats html
pardot_email_template html
pardot_forms html
pardot_lifecycle_histories html
pardot_lifecycle_stages html
pardot_list_memberships html
pardot_lists html
pardot_prospect_accounts html
pardot_prospects html
pardot_tag_objects html
pardot_tags html
pardot_users html
pardot_visitor_activities html
pardot_visitors html
pardot_visits html
set_credentials html
set_curl_options html
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'paRdot' in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
undefined exports: set_curl_options
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'paRdot' in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
undefined exports: set_curl_options
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
removing 'C:/Users/karan/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/paRdot'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)

I am on Windows 10 . 64 bit. Never saw this error before

Answer (score 0):

Works on R 3.5.1 once you update curl (mac osx)

Comment: Please be elaborative while providing answers.

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of R, it updates curl which fixes the install issue based on updates from the package author